# Streaming Movie in Flask App with Playback Length Control

Tags: flask, video-streaming, html5-video

**Description:**

I'm working on a Flask web application, and I'm trying to implement video streaming with the ability for users to control playback length and seek to different parts of the video. I have encountered some challenges in achieving this functionality.

**Problem Details:**

I have already set up a Flask route to stream a movie, but I'm not sure how to allow users to:

See the playback length (duration) of the video.
Change the playback time (seek) to a specific point in the video.
I mean i need generator or something to be memory effective.

Code Snippets:

Here's a simplified version of my Flask route for streaming the video:

python

```
@movie.route("/video/<name_url>")
def video(name_url: str):
    movie = Movie.query.filter_by(name_url=name_url).first()
    if movie:
        return send_from_directory(os.environ.get("MOVIE_DIR"), movie.src)
```

I'm using HTML5  element in my template to display the video.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="movie" align="middle">

  <video width="700" controls>
    <source src="{{url_for('movie.video', name_url=movie.name_url)}}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Specific Questions:**

How can I display the playback length (duration) of the video on the web page?
What should I do to allow users to change the playback time (seek) to a specific point in the video by, for example, dragging a slider or using input fields?

**Additional Context:**

I have researched this topic and found some resources related to video streaming, but I'm struggling with the playback control aspects and how to implement them in Flask.

I would appreciate any guidance or code examples that can help me achieve these features in my Flask application. Thank you for your help!